# Replace hash value

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hashes:

```
[{"__content__"=>"Guitars", "id"=>"2"},
 {"__content__"=>"For Guitars", "id"=>"3", "parentId"=>"2"},
 {"__content__"=>"6-string", "id"=>"24", "parentId"=>"2"},
 {"__content__"=>"7-string", "id"=>"25", "parentId"=>"2"},
 {"__content__"=>"8-string", "id"=>"26", "parentId"=>"2"}]
```

I want to replace the `parentId` values with the `__content__` values to get:

```
[{"__content__"=>"Guitars", "id"=>"2"},
 {"__content__"=>"For Guitars", "id"=>"3", "parentId"=>"Guitars"},
 {"__content__"=>"6-string", "id"=>"24", "parentId"=>"Guitars"},
 {"__content__"=>"7-string", "id"=>"25", "parentId"=>"Guitars"},
 {"__content__"=>"8-string", "id"=>"26", "parentId"=>"Guitars"}]
```

How can I do it?

Comment: So  value of `__content__` need to go in `parentId`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer to change this nasted `array` to `hash` for better maping.

**input**

```
arr = [
  {"__content__" => "Guitars", "id" => "2"},
  {"__content__" => "For Guitars", "id" => "3", "parentId" => "2"},
  {"__content__" => "6-string", "id" => "24", "parentId" => "2"},
  {"__content__" => "7-string", "id" => "25", "parentId" => "2"},
  {"__content__" => "8-string", "id" => "26", "parentId" => "2"}
]
```

**create parents**

```
parents = arr.each_with_object({}) { |h, exp| exp[h['id']] = h['__content__'] }
```

After this good map structure you can use simply `map` method.

**process**

```
output = arr.map do |h|
  h['parentId'] = parents[h['parentId']] if h['parentId'] && parents[h['parentId']]
  h
end
```

**output**

```
p output

# [
#   {"__content__" => "Guitars", "id" => "2"},
#   {"__content__" => "For Guitars", "id" => "3", "parentId" => "Guitars"},
#   {"__content__" => "6-string", "id" => "24", "parentId" => "Guitars"},
#   {"__content__" => "7-string", "id" => "25", "parentId" => "Guitars"},
#   {"__content__" => "8-string", "id" => "26", "parentId" => "Guitars"}
# ]
```

I hope this helps.

**EDIT**

You can also use this way

sort by ID

```
arr.sort_by! { |h| h['id'] }
```

**process**

```
output = arr.each_with_object({}) do |h, exp|
    exp[h['id']] = h
    h['parentId'] = exp[h['parentId']]['__content__'] if h['parentId'] && exp[h['parentId']]
    h
  end
```

after this you will have hash with id like keys, so for your output:

**output**

```
p output.values

# [
#  {"__content__"=>"Guitars", "id"=>"2"},
#  {"__content__"=>"6-string", "id"=>"24", "parentId"=>"Guitars"},
#  {"__content__"=>"7-string", "id"=>"25", "parentId"=>"Guitars"}, 
#  {"__content__"=>"8-string", "id"=>"26", "parentId"=>"Guitars"},
#  {"__content__"=>"For Guitars", "id"=>"3", "parentId"=>"Guitars"}
# ]
```

Comment: ,it works.Pretty complex,but in general it did what i need. thx

Comment: I upvoted, but have two suggestions for improving your answer. Firstly, when you present the solution you would use, adding an inferior alternative (here the one that uses `sort`) weakens your answer. (When there are two ways of doing something that does not have a clear winner, sure, present them both.) Secondly, I think most readers would like to see all the code in one place, rather than building it with explanations. You could either put the code first, then explain the steps (which readers who understand the code may skip) or give the steps in words before you present the code.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thank you for your suggestions. I will try to improve my answers.

Answer (score 1):

Beware! The solution below mutates the original hash!

```
▶ hashes = [{"__content__"=>"Guitars", "id"=>"2"},
▷   {"__content__"=>"For Guitars", "id"=>"3", "parentId"=>"2"}, 
▷   {"__content__"=>"6-string", "id"=>"24", "parentId"=>"2"}, 
▷   {"__content__"=>"7-string", "id"=>"25", "parentId"=>"2"}, 
▷   {"__content__"=>"8-string", "id"=>"26", "parentId"=>"2"}]   

hashes.each_with_object({}) do |h, memo|
  memo[h['id']] = h['__content__']
  h['parentId'] = memo[h['parentId']]
end

hashes
#⇒ [{"__content__"=>"Guitars", "id"=>"2", "parentId"=>nil},
#   {"__content__"=>"For Guitars", "id"=>"3", "parentId"=>"Guitars"},
#   {"__content__"=>"6-string", "id"=>"24", "parentId"=>"Guitars"},
#   {"__content__"=>"7-string", "id"=>"25", "parentId"=>"Guitars"},
#   {"__content__"=>"8-string", "id"=>"26", "parentId"=>"Guitars"}]
```

Comment: That's an interesting name for an array.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I love to tangle!

Comment: I've noticed. Me, I'm crushed by criticism.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I appended a locale ('es' in my case) to the original name and it seemed to fix everything :)

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [{"__content__"=>"Guitars", "id"=>"2"}, {"__content__"=>"For Guitars", "id"=>"3", "parentId"=>"2"}]

id_content_mapping = arr.reduce({}) do |h, elt|
  h[elt["id"]] = elt["__content__"]
  h
end

arr.map do |elt|
  if elt.has_key? "parentId"
    elt["parentId"] = id_content_mapping[elt["parentId"]]
  end
  elt
end
```